# Is there a more proper way to handle errors using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've never asked anything here, but there's something that bugs me.

You see, I'm toying with PHP for about a year. I've made myself quite a big project while learning PHP, JQuery, MySQL, etc.- it's far from being perfect, or even being finished, but it works and I'm constantly trying to improve existing code while adding new functions. It's a text-based browser MMORPG game (it's still in development), if you want a link, I'll provide it, but I didn't come here to promote it.

The thing is, I feel okay in procedural PHP (though I still have problems with repeating code), so I've decided it's about time to move to OOP. I understand it in theory, know the basics, and I'm slowly advancing in practice, but I wanted your advice, before moving too far.

In my original game with procedural code, I'm often doing something along these lines:

- user visits a page, say a shop.php. On opening the site, shop.php retrieves from database list of items that are available to buy. There are blank **#success-message** and **#error-message** paragraphs on the site.
- user then can choose an item from shop he wants to buy- clicking the item triggers javascript, and an AJAX call is made to the **buy-item.php**, expecting a json to be returned
- in buy-item.php I'm creating an array, say, **$result("success" => 0, "message" => "")**
- buy-item.php checks if the player can afford the item, has space in backpack, etc., and if there's one condition that isn't met, then $result["message"] sets to, say, "You need more gold". If all conditions are met, then result["success"] set's to 1, and $result["message"] to, say, "Purchase successful". Finally, it echoes **json_encode($result)** to AJAX.
- in AJAX **success:** I check **if(result.success)**, and act accordingly- If purchase was successful, I'd do **$("#error-message").html(result.message)**, and if it was successfull, I'd put result.message in "#success-message" instead (I could display both error and success messages in the same paragraph I guess, but that's simpler for me to do it separately, because these messages are styled differently, say, success is colored green, and error- red).

Now, is that a correct approach to handle errors? Or should I code it completely differently? Will this approach be still valid in OOP?

Let me show you what I mean with this example, I'm toying with at the moment (**for simplicity sake, please forget about security or even usefulness of the code**):

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl-PL">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <p id="error-message"></p>
            <p id="success-message"></p>
            <form id="registration-form" method="post">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Account Name" name="nickname"></input>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password"></input>
                <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="email"></input>
                <button type="submit">Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

class User{        
    //register method
    public function register($nickname, $password, $email){
        $result = array("success" => 0, "message" => "");
        //example validation
        if($nickname==123){
            $result["message"] = "Could not register.";
        }
        else{
            //add user to the database
            //sql code here
            $result["success"] = 1;
            $result["message"] = "Registration successful.";
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

?>
```

**registerProcessing.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'User.php';

    $user = new User();

    echo json_encode($user->register($_POST["nickname"], $_POST["password"], $_POST["email"]));
?>
```

**script.js**

```
$(function() {

    $("#wrapper").on("submit", "#registration-form", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "registerProcessing.php",
            data: $("#registration-form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result){
                if(result.success){
                    $("#success-message").html(result.message);
                }
                else{
                    $("#error-message").html(result.message);
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: You should probably try asking this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. You may get better responses there

Comment: and... avoid telling your life story before getting to your problem/question.

Comment: Haha, sorry Kevin, I just felt it would be appropriate in my first SO post to say few words about me, won't do that again, promise! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is study the ajax callbacks and states already made into javascript/jQuery and play with them. If you need more advanced kind of feature, will need to [send by backend](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) some headers forcing some statuses that can be handled by the proper callbacks or customized ones.

You can use the [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) mainly treated with major js libraries/frameworks (even the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) [pure itself that follow the HTTP pattern of codes, see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)).

Directly answering your question, no, is not right. Your ajax is using a main callback (success) and handling by returned values. It's works, but lacks best practices about callbacks, like I mentioned above.

An example what you can do:

```
$("#wrapper").on("submit", "#registration-form", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "registerProcessing.php",
            data: $("#registration-form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result){
                $("#success-message").html(result.message);
            },
            error: function(result){
               $("#error-message").html(result.message);
            }
        });
    });
```

or

```
$("#wrapper").on("submit", "#registration-form", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "registerProcessing.php",
            data: $("#registration-form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            statusCode: {
              404: function() {
                 $("#error-message").html('NOT FOUND');
              },
             200: function(result) {
                $("#success-message").html(result.message);
             },
             500: function(result) {
                $("#error-message").html(result.message);
             }
           }
        });
    });
```

Or with XMLHTTPREQUEST example:

```
var request;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
else
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
request.open('GET', 'http://www.mozilla.org', false);
request.send(); // there will be a 'pause' here until the response to come.
// the object request will be actually modified
switch (request.status){
   case 404:
    break;
   case 500:
    break;
   case 200;
   break
}
```

Comment: The status code can be 200 but the message can be an error.

Comment: That's why I recommended him study the manipulation of headers to send messages properly coded. That can be done with http_response_code, per example. http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: That's helpful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To add to @CarlosAlexandre's answer about handling errors using HTTP status codes: for your transition to OOP programming, you should be aware that it is becoming a best practice to use exception handling to pass error conditions around. This could like something like this:

**User.php**

```
class User{        
    //register method
    public function register($nickname, $password, $email){
        //example validation
        if($nickname==123){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid username');
        }

        //add user to the database
        //sql code here
    }
}
```

**registerProcessing.php**

```
require_once 'User.php';

$user = new User();
$response = array(
    'success' => 0,
    'message' => 'Unknown error',
);

try {
    $user->register($_POST["nickname"], $_POST["password"], $_POST["email"]);

    $response['success'] = 1;
    $response['message'] = 'Registration successful.';
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    $response['message'] = $exception->getMessage();
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, it's definitely helpful! :)